# Problem with Cormen's treatment of the Rabin-Karp algorithm

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, strings, rolling-hash

I am reading chapter 32 - String Matching from the book ["Introduction to Algorithms" 3rd edition Cormen et al](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262033844). The Rabin-Karp Algorithm is not clear to me despite heaving read it several times. Specifically, when the authors start proposing about some modulo operations for solving some problem, I am unable to follow. To be precise, the paragraphs from

> We have intentionally overlooked one problem: p and ts may be too
>   large too work with conveniently...

on till equation 32.2 (pp 991 in 3rd edition) are [the paragraphs I am having problems with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5ptz.jpg).

What does "convenient" mean here? Why do they use modulo? I am totally lost.
Is it possible to explain this in simple english?

I will appreciate if someone can help me in understanding this paragraph. And if there is any other reference (with similar mathematical treatment) where this can be read, please tell me.

Comment: This question would be better if you described the algorithm.  IIRC, you pick a linear function mod $p$ and then go left to right computing fingerprints.  If this is right, the point is that $p$ has to grow with $n$, so arithmetic isn't $O(1)$ per operation.

Comment: Perhaps the [Handbook of exact string matching algorithms](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/livres.html) helps.

Comment: how about the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) on said algorithm?